# how can I expand tree in ggtree?

Tags: r, ggplot2, phylogeny

Is there any way how to stretch the phylogenetic tree in ggtree along the y axis. I mean to do the same thing as does expansion in Figtree. Without this each terminal branch is too close to another if there are many tips.

Answer (score 1):

you can't expand y-axis interactively like what you did in Figtree.

In R, to expand y-axis (or x-axis if you want) is by saving your figure to file with a larger height (or width for x-axis).

If you have further question, please post in https://groups.google.com/d/forum/bioc-ggtree

### reference

**G Yu**, DK Smith, H Zhu, Y Guan, TTY Lam<sup>*</sup>. [ggtree: an R package for visualization and annotation of phylogenetic trees with their covariates and other associated data](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.12628/abstract). ***Methods in Ecology and Evolution***. [`doi:10.1111/2041-210X.12628`](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/2041-210X.12628).